# Does Moment of Courage proc during Duel using Legion Commander?

Tags: dota-2

When you Duel, all your skills have a bar over them, I'm not sure if Moment triggers or not during Duel. Does it? Is it better to max Press the Attack for Duel damage instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Moment of Courage can proc during Duel

Duel applies the Taunted status to both Legion Commander and her target, which combines a Silence (cannot manually activate abilities), a Mute (cannot manually activate items), and forces the unit to attack a specific target. Nothing about a Duel disables the passive effects of abilities of items, so Moment of Courage can proc during a Duel.

That said, Overwhelming Odds and Press the Attack are more useful to guarantee a Duel victory in the early game.
Overwhelming Odds is a potentially very strong AoE nuke that boosts Legion Commander's movement speed, allowing her to get in range for a followup Duel.
Press the Attack offers huge utility thanks to its ability to be cast on allies, in cases where a strong dispel can mean the difference between life and death. At the same time, increased attack speed and health regen will make it more likely to win a Duel. As of patch 7.20, winning a duel will automatically activate the effects of Press the Attack on Legion Commander, so levelling up this skill early will provide a nice chunk of regen after every Duel win.
Moment of Courage, on the other hand, will proc depending on the target's attack speed. Early on, Legion Commander wants to Duel squishy targets that don't deal much damage, and have low attack speed. This makes it unlikely to even get a single proc of Moment of Courage during the entirety of a Duel.